# Turn a data set into a matrix using headers as the row and columns of the matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataset

I have a data set (showing is just a snapshot) and I need to create a matrix with treatment as the rows and years as the columns.  Inside the matrix needs to contain the mean and variance of the Y column.

```
Y<-c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,0,2)
Treatment<-c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Year<-c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
dat<-as.data.frame(cbind(Y,Treatment,Year))
print(dat)

      Y Treatment Year
1     0         0    1
2     1         0    2
3     1         0    3
4     1         0    4
5     0         1    5
6     0         1    1
7     0         1    2
8     2         1    3
9     0         1    4
10    2         1    5
```

I would like my matrix to show the mean and variance of the Y column.

Comment: The data set is http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/fitzmaur/ala/skin.txt

Comment: I already manipulated the data set so only the relevant columns are showing using skin.data.matrix=skin.data[7:9]

Comment: Can you edit your question with the comments you have posted? Could you also show us what you have tried and your expected output of the question.

Comment: Do you just want something like `with(dat, tapply(Y, list(Treatment,Year), FUN=mean) )` as output?

Comment: I provided a solution but I think that at this point you have to provide a desired output because it is not clear to me your ideal output (i figured a 2 x 5 matrix) but you also say that you want means and variances. Very hard to fit 20 elements in a 10 elements matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
library(reshape2)
as.matrix(dcast(Treatment ~ Year, data = df, value.var = "Y", fun.aggregate = mean))
     Treatment 1 2 3 4   5
[1,]         0 0 1 1 1 NaN
[2,]         1 0 0 2 0   1
```

Comment: `dcast(Treatment ~ Year, data = dat, value.var = "Y", fun.aggregate=mean)` to get the mean values. Change to `var` to get the variance.

Comment: @thelatemail thank you for you comment, I forget to set the function  mean even though at the moment the user intent is still not clear to me because the desired matrix seems to be a 2 x 5 but he wants means and variances inside it.

Comment: It's not clear to me either and OP seems to have vanished for now. I guess we wait for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Y<-c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,0,2)
Treatment<-c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Year<-c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
dat<-cbind(Y,Treatment,Year)
meanY<-mean(Y)
varY<-var(y)
dat1<-cbind(dat,meanY,varY)
print(dat1)
     Y Treatment Year meanY     varY
 [1,] 0         0    1   0.7 19.09091
 [2,] 1         0    2   0.7 19.09091
 [3,] 1         0    3   0.7 19.09091
 [4,] 1         0    4   0.7 19.09091
 [5,] 0         1    5   0.7 19.09091
 [6,] 0         1    1   0.7 19.09091
 [7,] 0         1    2   0.7 19.09091
 [8,] 2         1    3   0.7 19.09091
 [9,] 0         1    4   0.7 19.09091
[10,] 2         1    5   0.7 19.09091
```

If you calculate the value and add it as a column to the matrix or dataframe R will make extend the length of the column.